# How to get state values from custom component to another parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-places-api

I have 2 classes (both React.Component). Let's say, that one of these is my own component, which also built on another custom component (in my case, it's [React Places Autocomplete](https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete/)).
[Just look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cq0g.png)

Code here:

```js
//App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PlaceAutocomplete from "./places_autocomplete";

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { output: '' };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <PlaceAutocomplete/>
                <p>{this.state.output}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;


//places_autocomplete.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './PlaceAutocomplete.css';
import PlacesAutocomplete from 'react-places-autocomplete';

class PlaceAutocomplete extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { address: '', output: '' };
    }

    handleChange = address => {
        this.setState({ address });
    };

    handleSelect = async address => {
        this.setState({address: address});
        this.state.output = address;
        document.getElementById('lsi').blur();
    };

    searchOptions = {
        types: ['(cities)']
    };

    hidden = (suggest) => {
        return suggest == null || suggest === ""
            ? "autocomplete-dropdown-container-hidden"
            : "autocomplete-dropdown-container";
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <PlacesAutocomplete
                value={this.state.address}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                onSelect={this.handleSelect}
                searchOptions={this.searchOptions}>
                {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
                    <div>
                        <input value={this.state.address}
                               id={'lsi'}
                            {...getInputProps({
                                placeholder: 'Select a city',
                                className: 'location-search-input',
                            })}/>
                        <div className={this.hidden(suggestions[1])}>
                            {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                            {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                                const className = suggestion.active
                                    ? "suggestion-item--active"
                                    : "suggestion-item";
                                // inline style for demonstration purpose
                                const style = suggestion.active
                                    ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer' }
                                    : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer' };
                                return (
                                    <div
                                        {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                                            className: className,
                                            style,
                                        })}
                                    >
                                        <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </PlacesAutocomplete>
        );
    }
}

export default PlaceAutocomplete;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

So, you can see how I tried to find a solution for this. This code mostly looks ugly, because I don't know any other way to implement these feautures.

System info:

- The latest React for 17.08.2018 (I don't really remember, but I do know that it's the latest (I installed it just 1 week ago).
- This application created by CRA (Create React Application) template. So please, if your solution won't work with this template (I think there's different styles, like ES6 etc. But it's not the point) then add at least an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try lifting the state up to the parent component and use callbacks to share the data. As stated by the react docs, there should be a single "source of truth" for data changes in a React application - this reduces potential bugs and duplicated code. Take a look at . https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html